# overiding policy.xml on docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, imagemagick

I was following the link https://help.heroku.com/RFDJQSG3/how-can-i-override-imagemagick-settings-in-a-policy-xml-file to override the default policy.xml of mini magic, but it is not happning.

Step taken by me.

1. I created an `.magic/policy.xml` in my root_path
2. In my environment i set the  `"MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH" => "/app/.magick/:/etc/ImageMagick-6/",`

but still when i try `identify -list policy`

i still have result

```
Path: /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
  Policy: undefined
    rights: None 
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: EPHEMERAL
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: URL
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: HTTPS
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: MVG
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: MSL
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: TEXT
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: SHOW
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: WIN
  Policy: Coder
    rights: None 
    pattern: PLT
  Policy: Path
    rights: None 
    pattern: @*

Path: [built-in]
  Policy: Undefined
    rights: None
```

It is not getting overrided.

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php for a list of directories where it can be installed. They are prioritized from most to least.

Answer (score 0):

If the user/app policies are not being listed, then it's usually a simple XML error, and ImageMagick is silently skipping the `policy.xml` file.

Sometimes, the full XML header is needed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policymap [
<!ELEMENT policymap (policy)+>
<!ELEMENT policy (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST policy domain (delegate|coder|filter|path|resource) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy name CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy rights CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy pattern CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<policymap>
    <!-- ... -->
</policymap>
```

Also, environment variable can just be:

```
MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH=/app/.magick
```

The "/etc/ImageMagick-6/" path is system-level configration, and is defined at compile time.

Comment: i was able to get policies listed, buy still my problem was not solved.

Comment: Please have a look on my main problem `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038764/minimagick-error-during-upload-composite-compose-over-gravity-north' i thought that it was due to some memory issue, but i can't figure it out , can you please help